Docusign embedded signing wouldn't load on iphones but loads fine on other devices(mobiles/desktop)
I have been having issues with docusign embedded signing on iphone. I did research about it and found out that the iphones doesn't go hand in hand with iframes, I shall go for webview instead but that too isn't loading embedded signing.
What else I should I look into? Any help will be appreciated.
Below is the current implementation that would load for all devices other than iphones.
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { logError } from "../../utils/Logger";

const DocumentSignUI = ({
  integrationKey,
  docUrl,
  mutateUpdateDocumentSignStatus,
  contextHolder,
}) => {
  const [signingStatus, setSigningStatus] = useState(false);
  const signingStatusRef = useRef(signingStatus);
  const mutationTimeoutRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    signingStatusRef.current = signingStatus;
  }, [signingStatus]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadDocuSign = async () => {
      try {
        const docusign = await window.DocuSign.loadDocuSign(integrationKey);
        const url = `${docUrl}&output=embed`.replace("https://", "");

        const signing = docusign.signing({
          url,
          displayFormat: "focused",
        });
        signing.on("sessionEnd", (_event) => {
          if (!signingStatusRef.current) {
            setSigningStatus(true);

            if (mutationTimeoutRef.current) {
              clearTimeout(mutationTimeoutRef.current);
            }

            mutationTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
              mutateUpdateDocumentSignStatus.mutateAsync();
              mutationTimeoutRef.current = null;
            }, 1000);
          }
        });

        signing.mount("#agreement");
      } catch (ex) {
        logError(ex);
      }
    };
    loadDocuSign();

    return () => {
      if (mutationTimeoutRef.current) {
        clearTimeout(mutationTimeoutRef.current);
      }
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {contextHolder}
      <div className="docusign-agreement" id="agreement" />
    </>
  );
};

DocumentSignUI.propTypes = {
  integrationKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  docUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  mutateUpdateDocumentSignStatus: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  contextHolder: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default DocumentSignUI;


Changed implementation and appended webview tag inside of div tag but same result.
Below is the controller function to create recepient view
loadDocusignDocument: async (req, res) => {
try {
  let userData = "";
  const { name, email } = req.body;

  await docusignCheckToken.checkToken(req);

  const apiClient = new docusign.ApiClient({
    basePath: basePath,
    oAuthBasePath: oAuthBasePath + "/oauth/token",
  });

  apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", `Basic ${docusignAuthToken}`);

  userData = await apiClient.getUserInfo(req.session.access_token);

  const baseUri = userData.accounts[0].baseUri;
  const accountDomain = baseUri.split("/v2");
  apiClient.setBasePath(accountDomain[0] + "/restapi");

  const downloadedDocument = await docusignCheckToken.downloadDocument(req);

  const envelopeArgs = {
    signerEmail: email,
    signerName: name,
    signerClientId: docusignClientId,
    docFile: downloadedDocument,
    status: "created",
  };
  const envelope = docusignCheckToken.makeEnvelope(envelopeArgs);

  const envelopesApi = await docusignCheckToken.getEnvelopes(req);

  const userEnvelopeResult = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(
    userData.accounts[0].accountId,
    { envelopeDefinition: envelope }
  );

  const recepientRequest = {
    dsReturnUrl: frontendUrl + "dashboard/success",
    signerEmail: email,
    signerName: name,
    signerClientId: docusignClientId,
  };

  const viewRequest = await docusignCheckToken.makeRecipientViewRequest(
    recepientRequest
  );

  const viewRequestResult = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(
    userData.accounts[0].accountId,
    userEnvelopeResult.envelopeId,
    {
      recipientViewRequest: viewRequest,
      frameAncestors: [
        frontendUrl + "dashboard/sign-document",
        docusignAppDomain,
      ],
      messageOrigins: [docusignAppDomain],
      signerEmail: email,
      signerName: name,
    }
  );

  res.status(200).json({
    envelopeId: userEnvelopeResult.envelopeId,
    redirectUrl: viewRequestResult.url,
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error processing request:", error);
  res.status(500).json({
    success: false,
    message: "An error occurred while processing the request",
  });
}

},
And utils function below
    module.exports = {
  checkToken: async (req) => {
    try {
      const docusignAuthToken = config.get("docusign.authorizationToken");
      const apiClient = new docusign.ApiClient({
        basePath: basePath,
        oAuthBasePath: oAuthBasePath + "/oauth/token",
      });

      apiClient.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", `Basic ${docusignAuthToken}`);

      const scopes = [oAuth.Scope.IMPERSONATION, oAuth.Scope.SIGNATURE];

      if (!(req.session.access_token && Date.now() < req.session.expires_at)) {
        jWTResponse = await apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(
          docusignClientId,
          docusignUserGUID,
          scopes,
          docusignRSAKey,
          36000
        );

        req.session.access_token = jWTResponse.body.access_token;

        req.session.expires_at =
          Date.now() + (jWTResponse.body.expires_in - 60) * 1000;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while checking token:", error);
    }
  },
  getEnvelopes: async (req) => {
    let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
    dsApiClient.setBasePath(basePath);
    dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader(
      "Authorization",
      "Bearer " + req.session.access_token
    );
    return new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient);
  },

  makeEnvelope: (args) => {
    let env = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
    env.emailSubject = "Please sign this document";

    let doc1 = new docusign.Document();
    let doc1b64 = Buffer.from(args.docFile.buffer).toString("base64");
    doc1.documentBase64 = doc1b64;
    doc1.name = "Lorem Ipsum";
    doc1.fileExtension = "pdf";
    doc1.documentId = "3";

    env.documents = [doc1];

    let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
      email: args.signerEmail,
      name: args.signerName,
      clientUserId: args.signerClientId,
      recipientId: 1,
    });

    let signHere1 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
      anchorString: "/sn1/",
      anchorYOffset: "10",
      anchorUnits: "pixels",
      anchorXOffset: "20",
    });
    let signer1Tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
      signHereTabs: [signHere1],
    });
    signer1.tabs = signer1Tabs;

    let recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
      signers: [signer1],
    });
    env.recipients = recipients;
    env.status = "sent";

    return env;
  },
  makeRecipientViewRequest: (args) => {
    let viewRequest = new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();
    viewRequest.returnUrl = args.dsReturnUrl;

    viewRequest.authenticationMethod = "none";

    viewRequest.email = args.signerEmail;
    viewRequest.userName = args.signerName;
    viewRequest.clientUserId = args.signerClientId;

    viewRequest.frameAncestors = [
      frontendUrl + "dashboard/sign-document",
      docusignAppDomain,
    ];
    viewRequest.messageOrigins = [docusignAppDomain];

    return viewRequest;
  },
  downloadDocument: async (req) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(req.body.url, {
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};


Please edit your question to add your call to the create recipient view API. That's probably where your error is

Hey @LarryK, I have edit and included the api controller in the question

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please "check" (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!

Your code has a couple of issues:
EnvelopeViews:createRecipient -- frameAncestors
Major issue
The frameAncestors property must only include URL origins; URL paths are not allowed--
// Currently:
viewRequest.frameAncestors = [
   frontendUrl + "dashboard/sign-document",
   docusignAppDomain,
];

// Update to only include the origins. Eg
viewRequest.frameAncestors = [
   "https://app.domain.com", // Do not include a trailing slash (/)
   docusignAppDomain,
];

Because you're including the path, (the part after the domain name), it is not working on Safari, WKWebView, and other Apple systems.
See my blog post to learn more including Postel's law.
Also see this Docusign JS doc.
EnvelopeViews:createRecipient -- returnUrl
Minor issue
The returnUrl property is only used when Docusign JS is not used. When Docusign JS is not used, the resulting recipient view redirects the browser to the supplied returnUrl. But when Docusign JS is used, an iframe is automatically created and used; there is no redirect when the signing session is done. Instead, a JavaScript event is raised.
Bottom line: while you still may need to supply the returnUrl property, it is not used if Docusign JS is used.
Munging the recipient view URL
Not a good idea
The EnvelopeViews:createRecipient API call returns the recipient view URL. On the browser, this URL is a request attribute for the Docusign JS signing library.
Currently, your code is munging the URL:
const url = `${docUrl}&output=embed`.replace("https://", "");

const signing = docusign.signing({
    url,
    displayFormat: "focused"
});

I don't know why you're doing this, but it isn't a good idea.
